# Can't set value to $_SESSION variable in MVC model

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, model-view-controller, model

I am trying to create a persistent session variable in a model in code igniter.
This is what I have at the top of my model before the class starts:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userscore'];
```

Inside the class I have this two functions:
The first one I am trying to set the current score to the session variable so later on I can call it in the second function and return the current total score.The score reaches the function **setscore**. 
I just cant understand how to set the variable at the top of the page with this value.I tough that the variable session is global. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
function setscore($score){
        $_SESSION['userscore'] = $score;

}
function getscore(){
        $totalscore = $_SESSION['userscore'];
        return $totalscore;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to manually initialize session and access to superglobal $_SESSION. CodeIgniter already make way for you to use session. Just simply use like this in your controller:

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        //load the session library
        $this->load->driver('session');

        //set custom field
        $this->session->set_userdata('name', 'david');

        //get custom field
        $this->session->userdata('name');

        //unset field
        $this->session->unset_userdata('name');
    }
}
```

If you're using framework, stick to what framework provide and some best practice the framework suggest.

Regards,

Comment: I am trying to have a persistent variable in my model, and have been told to use sessions. Is there another way I can store the score for question and add to the total score until the user decides to stop playing the quiz?

Comment: @Otonel the other way would be to use a database reference, but sessions will be much easier.

Comment: @Otonel I also recommend using session for this. Notice that score of each question, although need to carry to next request, is just temporary for a couple requests. And that best suited for session variable. Storing in database would work also, but it's proper for something that last for long time. In your case the total score of each play would be better store in database. Regards,